# "An account with that identifier already exists" on Apple Watch when signing in with Apple ID

Tags: apple-id, apple-watch, apple-watch.app

When I try to sign in to my Apple ID on my Apple Watch Series 2 (watchOS 4.2), I get an error stating that "*An account with that identifier already exists*".

The Watch App on my paired iPhone seems to think I haven't signed in on my Apple Watch before. (*Apple Watch → General Apple ID → Sign In*). However, my watch is already registered when I check the [manage your Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/) page.

What does this error mean? How do I fix it?

[image: Could Not Sign In: An account with that identifier already exists]

Comment: Can you try to unpair the Watch and then pair it again?  That might help and you wouldn't have to erase the contents to do it.

Comment: @fsb The last time I unpaired my watch I had to do a reset, followed by a restore from backup.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct Apple ID?  The only time I've seen that error message is if you're trying to use an ID that's already in use by someone else.

Comment: @fsb I’m using the same Apple ID I use for my iPhone and iTunes.

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you have any such with it?